# memory management in vector<T> in c++

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a class named as Animal and it has a method which is virtual so the class becomes the virtual class.

```
class Animal
{ 
   virtual double eat() = 0;
};
```

i have two more classes they are cat and dog and these classes inherits from animal.

and there is fourth class -zoo- and it has a field

```
  vector<Animal *> animals;
```

i am pushing the cat and dog instances to the animals vector of zoo object.

at any time i want to clear zoo instance and i also want the vector of this object is deleted. and i also want the objects of vector of this objects is deleted.

what exactly should i do. 
all the classes except for zoo have only float fields (no pointers). (float a,b etc.)
so can we say that there is no need to deal with animal objects since they dont have any pointers.

where should i write destructor. In a base class(animal) or in a subclasses(cat - dog) or nowhere
or how should i write these destructors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you need to declare a give `Animal` a virtual destructor:

```
class Animal
{ 
   virtual double eat() = 0;
 public:
   virtual ~Animal() {}
};
```

This is required such that calling `delete` on an `Animal` pointer will call the destructor of the type of the object the pointer points to. Doing this without a virtual destructor results in undefined behaviour.

Next, you need to call `delete` on all dynamically allocated `Animals`:

```
for (auto a : animals)
  delete a;
```

Then, you can clear the vector:

```
animals.clear();
```

This is required if you need to use `animals` for something else. You don't need to do this in the `zoo` destructor.

Alternatively, you can use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>>` and forget about the manual memory management.

Comment: Let me add that `std::shared_ptr<Animal>` is likely the better choice. However, neither `unique_ptr<>` nor `shared_ptr<>` are perfect.

Comment: @cmaster I would have though a zoo owned its animals, so `shared_ptr` wouldn't be the best choice. But I don't think there is enough information either way.

Comment: I didn't want to criticize you in any way, I just wanted to **add** to your answer that there might be better alternatives. There is tons of use cases that would require a `shared_ptr` in similar situations.

Comment: @cmaster No worries, I didn't take it as a criticism :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza from your answer i understood that i dont need to write manuel operations in zoo destructor, but if i do this in there then it is also ok.  i dont need any destructor in subclasses and if i write these operations in zoo destructor delete zoo will be enough? am i right?

Comment: @bttb As far as I can see, you only need to loop over `animals` deleting the elements in the `zoo` destructor. For the other classes, it sounds like the default, compiler-generated destructor is enough.

Comment: Just a nit, but you'll note that formally, your for loop causes undefined behavior.  (In this case, formally or not, the probability of any implementation misbehaving is low enough that I wouldn't worry about it, and would use the same code.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Sorry, I'm a but slow today. What causes UB in the loop?

Comment: You might point out just how dangerous what he's doing is.  Anyone can assign to a pointer in the vector, which means that the previous pointer leaks.  Using `unique_ptr` solves this, but adds its own set of problems: a strange syntax to access the pointers, for example.  Better than either would be to use a pointer vector, but the only real solution is to avoid having the container "own" the objects to begin with.  (In pedantic programs like this, it may not be possible, but in real code, it's very, very rare for a container to own objects it hasn't itself constructed.)

Comment: One of the requirements of a container is that its elements be copiable and assignable.  Once you've deleted through a pointer, that pointer is no longer either.  (Of course, realistically, implementations don't copy for no reason, and if the next operation is a `clear` or the destructor, I can't imagine the code not working.  Not to mention that copying a pointer to deleted memory doesn't cause problems on most implementations, even if it is undefined behavior.)

Comment: That particular case of UB is trivially fixable: `for (auto & a : animals) { delete a; a = nullptr; }` or hyper-correct `for (auto & a : animals) { Animal p = nullptr; std::swap(a, p); delete p; }`